# Cómo puedo modificar el clásico código de búsqueda binaria para buscar palabras ya ingresadas y guardadas en un arreglo de chars?

Tags: c++, método, búsquedas

**`*`texto en negrita`*`**He intentado modifcar el codigo de busqueda binaria de esta manera, pero me da un error es que creo que no puedo summar +1 a la variable "central", ya que es de tipo estructura, alguna sugerencia?[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: se le escapó el "de esta manera" =P

Comment: intenté subir una imagen, pero no se subió jajaja por eso dije "de esta manera" lol

Comment: en texto va mejor, para mobile y poder chequear la sintaxis con el coloreo que le hace el interprete

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento del sitio y de paso ganes tu primera medalla, 
también es muy importante que leas [Ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que esta sea bien recibida por la comunidad

Comment: Las [imagenes no compilan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5508110/why-is-this-program-erroneously-rejected-by-three-c-compilers) pon el código.

Answer (score 0):

## include

## include

## include

//Se tiene un diccionario electronico con n palabras y sus respectivos significados,
//busque una palabra y muestre su significado. usar busqueda binaria

struct ejercicio{
    char Palabra[30];
    char significado[100];
};

using namespace std;

void CantPalabras(int &n);
void PedirDatos(ejercicio A[100],int);
void QuickSort(ejercicio A[],int,int);
int busquedaBinaria(ejercicio d[], int n, char palabra[]);
void mostrar(ejercicio A[],int);

int main()
{
    ejercicio A[100];
    int n;
    char dato[20];

```
CantPalabras(n);
PedirDatos(A,n);
QuickSort(A,0,n-1);
cout<<"PALABRAS ORDENADAS ALFABETICAMENTE:"<<endl;
mostrar(A,n);
cout<<endl;

cout<<"Ingrese una palabra a buscar: ";
cin.getline(dato,20);
cout<<endl;


if(busquedaBinaria(A,n,dato)== -1)
{
    cout<<"LO SENTIMOS, la palabra "<<dato<<" no se ha encontrado :(";
    cout<<endl<<endl;
}
else
{
    cout<<"FELICIDADES, la palabra "<<A[busquedaBinaria(A,n,dato)].Palabra<<" si se encontro! :)"<<endl;
    cout<<"Su significado es: "<<A[busquedaBinaria(A,n,dato)].significado<<endl<<endl;
}

return 0;
```

}

void CantPalabras(int &n)
{
    cout<<"Ingrese cuantas palabras va a ingresar: ";
    cin>>n;
    cout<

void PedirDatos(ejercicio A[100],int n)
{
    for(int i=0;i

void QuickSort(ejercicio A[], int primero, int ultimo)
{
     int i=primero,j=ultimo;
     ejercicio pivote;
     ejercicio temp;

```
 pivote=A[(primero+ultimo)/2];

 do{

    while(strcmp(A[i].Palabra,pivote.Palabra)<0 && i<ultimo)
    {
        i++;
    }

    while(strcmp(A[j].Palabra,pivote.Palabra)>0 && j>primero)
    {
        j--;
    }

    if(i<=j)
    {
         temp=A[i];
         A[i]=A[j];
         A[j]=temp;
         i++;
         j--;
    }
 }while(i<=j);

 if(i<ultimo)
 {
    QuickSort(A,i,ultimo);
 }

 if(primero<j)
 {
    QuickSort(A,primero,j);
 }
```

}

void mostrar(ejercicio A[],int n)
{
    for(int i=0;i

int busquedaBinaria(ejercicio A[], int n, char variable[])
{
     int izq,der,central;
     izq = 0;
     der = n-1;
     central = (izq+der)/2;
     while (strcmp(variable,A[central].Palabra)!=0 && izq <= der ){
         if(strcmp(variable,A[central].Palabra)>0)
            izq = central+1;
         else
             der = central-1;
             central=(izq+der)/2;
     }
     if (strcmp(variable,A[central].Palabra)==0)
        return central;
     else
        return -1;
}